# Is it correct to compare the modulo of two double values with an integer in Java?

Tags: java, modulo

This code is working fine now but will it give correct answers in all cases ?

Here is my code:

```
double val1 = 0.75;
double val2 = 0.25;

if(val1 % val2 == 0){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: It depends on what the condition is. If you want to check isCompeletly divisible you should check for Zero.

Comment: I don't know what you consider "mathematically correct"; [section 15.17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) of the Java Language Specification explains exactly what the `%` operator computes. Read that and decide for yourself if it does what you expect.

Comment: @Jesper question edited, I mean will it give correct answers in all cases, because I found that 3.9 % 0.1 gives wrong answer

Comment: What does "correct answers" mean? What answer did you expect from 3.9 % 0.1 and why do you think that what you got was incorrect?

Comment: @Mritunjay I only want to check if val1 is completely divisible by val2

Comment: As @Jesper point it, there is a section about that, saying floating point are valid value for `%` and how it will be computed. Reading it would be a good think if you decide to use this, as it is always better to document yourself on a solution ;)

Comment: You may run into rounding problems. If you can define a max number of digits you should check `(int) (v1 * DIGIT_COUNT) % (int) (v2 * DIGIT_COUNT) == 0`. For e. g. 5 digits set `DIGIT_COUNT = 100000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer, you should compare it with small value rather than an integer, the reason is:

Consider there two values: `1.0 and 0.1`. If you do `1.0 % 0.1`, it will give `0.09999999999999995`, as the result of a rounding error. So here if you are comparing with Integer, it will return false.

So as mentioned in answer of @MauricePerry , following is the best practice.

```
Math.abs(val1 % val2) < EPSILON //where EPSILON is a small value
```

Comment: Can I do (Math.abs(val1 % val2) == 0)

Comment: Its same as you were doing previously. Math.abs() is for absolute value. @AnkurLathiya

Comment: do something like: `Math.abs(val1 % val2) < 0.0001`

Comment: what would be the value of EPSILON ?

Comment: it can be any small value like 0.0001 or 0.00001 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that: for these values, the result may be correct, but probably not with, say 0.6 and 0.2.

UPDATE

BTW: the integer you're comparing the modulo with (0) will be converted into a double before the comparison.

Comment: I always do modulo with 0.25

Comment: @AnkurLathiya I wouldn't do that

Comment: what should I " if(val1 % val2 == 0) " with better one

Comment: If you are not sure, as you said you always have the same divider, simply multiply the value, trim the decimal part, and do the check based on the new value.

Comment: @AnkurLathiya I would do Math.abs(val1 % val2) < EPSILON, where EPSILON is a small value.

Comment: @AxelH  didnt get sir, which value multiply with which one and what to do next

Comment: EPSILON is a small *positive* value ;-) Depending on your use case e.g. 0.0001 or 0.0000000001, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes!**

`%,` also known as the modulus or remainder operator. The % operator returns the remainder of two numbers. For instance 10 % 3 is 1 because 10 divided by 3 leaves a remainder of 1.
for more :[go through this link](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/modulus.html)